# LMM: How do I calculate a standard deviation on the variance explained by fixed effects?

Tags: r, mixed-model, variance, standard-deviation

So, building a LMM with the `lmer` function in `lme4`, you get the variance explained by the variance component.

```
summary(esoph) # data on esophageal cancer from 'datasets' package

     agegp          alcgp         tobgp        ncases         ncontrols    
  25-34:15   0-39g/day:23   0-9g/day:24   Min.   : 0.000   Min.   : 1.00  
  35-44:15   40-79    :23   10-19   :24   1st Qu.: 0.000   1st Qu.: 3.00  
  45-54:16   80-119   :21   20-29   :20   Median : 1.000   Median : 6.00  
  55-64:16   120+     :21   30+     :20   Mean   : 2.273   Mean   :11.08  
  65-74:15                                3rd Qu.: 4.000   3rd Qu.:14.00  
  75+  :11                                Max.   :17.000   Max.   :60.00

# Just a hypothetical mixed model
m1 <- lmer(ncase~ncontrols+(1|tobgp)+(1|agegp), data=esoph, REML=F)
summary(m1)

Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood  ['lmerMod']
Formula: ncases ~ ncontrols + (1 | tobgp) + (1 | agegp)
   Data: esoph

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   404.0    416.4   -197.0    394.0       83 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.0267 -0.4770 -0.0704  0.3030  5.8282 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 agegp    (Intercept) 2.2809   1.5103  
 tobgp    (Intercept) 0.0293   0.1712  
 Residual             4.4311   2.1050  
Number of obs: 88, groups:  agegp, 6; tobgp, 4

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)  1.65533    0.69209   2.392
ncontrols    0.05022    0.01882   2.668
```

I get the standard deviation for each of my variance components. Let's say I want to compute variance explained by my fixed effects (code from [here](http://jonlefcheck.net/2013/03/13/r2-for-linear-mixed-effects-models/)):

```
(VarF <- var(as.vector(lme4::fixef(m1) %*% t(m1@pp$X))))
# 0.4082163
```

Great! That's useful information! How do I go about calculating the standard deviation for this variance estimate?

Comment: One option is a parametric bootstrap (for this, and many derived quantities). You can use the `bootMer()` function in `lme4`, passing the function you give above, then calculate the standard deviation of the bootstrap replicates; this will approximate the standard error of the statistic of interest. For example, `vfix<-function(m) var(as.vector(fixef(m1) %*% t(m1@pp$X))); samples<-bootMer(m1, FUN=vfix, nsim=999); sd(samples$t)`

Comment: In a non-mixed effects model, the 'variance explained' is $R^2$. Are you asking about the analog of $R^2$ for LMMs, & how to get a standard error for $R^2$?

Comment: gung, I'm using the Marginal and Conditional R^2 from Nakagawa and Schielzeth (2013). It's a little unconventional, but I want to compare response magnitude between fixed and random effects (so show the variance explained from the fixed effects components along with variance explained by random effects, just as a bar graph instead of as a ratio).

Comment: `getME(m1,"X")` is simpler and more reliable than `m1@pp$X` ...

Comment: I believe something like `sqrt(diag(X %*% vcov(m1) %*% t(X)))` will do it (I may have the transposition in the wrong place)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The std deviations given in the summary for a linear mixed model are not the std deviation for the variance estimates, they are just the estimates for the std deviation of the effects themselves, that is the square-roots of the variance estimates.
Thus, even if you calculate the std deviation of the fixed-effects variance estimate, you will not be able to compare the fixed and random variances on a graph using the random std deviations given by the summary.